# Index out of range in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, cell

I am trying to display 2 different types of data in table view. The videoNews Array only has one element that is to be displayed in **indexPath.row == 1** and Suggested News array has many elements that are to be displayed in **indexPath.row >= 4**. Everything in between are just labels and go as it is. The problem comes when elements from SuggestedNews array are displayed the tableView gives **index out of range** error even though the array has elements and numberOfRowsInSection also gets the right number of elements.

**Code of TableView**

```
var SuggestedNews = [VideoNews]()
var videoNews = [VideoNews]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (5 + SuggestedNews.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoArticleCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoArticleCell {

            let video = self.videoNews[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateUI(video: video)

            return cell
        }
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoFirstLabelCell") {

            return cell
        }
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoSubmissionCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoSubmissionCell {

            return cell
        }
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoSecondLabelCell") {

            return cell
        }
    } else if indexPath.row >= 4 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoSuggestionCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoSuggestionCell {

            let latest = self.SuggestedNews[indexPath.row] //Index out of range
            cell.updateUI(latest: latest)

            return cell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If index.row == 4 your code in this line but you want to show first element of array; therefore, your first array index is equal to 0.

`let latest = self.SuggestedNews[indexPath.row - 4]`

If you have 4 cell different than SuggestedNews, your return don't be `return (5 + SuggestedNews.count)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (4 + SuggestedNews.count)
}
```

Comment: Can you try change return value like the above

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you so much. Seems like it was a silly overlook.